# v5 UUID. What is difference between UUID of the namespace and name

Tags: c, uuid

I am trying to generate a v5 UUID by  referring to the function (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) :

```
/* uuid_create_sha1_from_name -- create a version 5 (SHA-1) UUID
   using a "name" from a "name space" */
void uuid_create_sha1_from_name(
    uuid_t *uuid,         /* resulting UUID */
    uuid_t nsid,          /* UUID of the namespace */
    void *name,           /* the name from which to generate a UUID */
    int namelen           /* the length of the name */
);
```

I have read the help, but I am still not clear on what is the difference between the 2nd(`uuid_t nsid`) and 3rd (`void *name`) parameters of above function?

Could someone explain me the above with an example ?

I would also like to understand what the below means in the RFC4122 link and does it have any significance to the 2nd parameter ?

```
/* Name string is a URL */
uuid_t NameSpace_URL = { /* 6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 */
    0x6ba7b811,
    0x9dad,
    0x11d1,
    0x80, 0xb4, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x4f, 0xd4, 0x30, 0xc8
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `name` is the key that is unique to whatever thing you're generating uuid's for

The `namespace` is a constant UUID that identifies the context in which you're generating UUIDs

If you look at the RFC, you'll see section 4.3 defines these characteristics of a name-baesed UUID:

- The UUIDs generated at different times from the same name in the
  same namespace MUST be equal.
- The UUIDs generated from two different names in the same namespace
  should be different (with very high probability).
- The UUIDs generated from the same name in two different namespaces
  should be different with (very high probability).
- If two UUIDs that were generated from names are equal, then they
  were generated from the same name in the same namespace (with very
  high probability).

These are all important properties to have in a name-based UUID.   For example, let's say you and I are implementing HR systems for our respective companies.  The systems are completely unrelated to one another, but because UUIDs are awesome, we're both using name-based UUIDs to identify employees.  And because it's a rather obvious thing to do, we use employee names as the `name` from which the UUIDs are generated.

Without namespaces we would both create the same UUID for anyone named "John Smith"... but that'd be Bad (tm) since our systems are unrelated and we're dealing with different John Smiths.  "So what," you say!  ... but what happens when our companies merge next year and we have to combine our HR databases?  Well, at that point we find ourselves merging database records that have the same ID and pretty soon the paychecks for every John Smith in the company are crossing in the mail and HR is handing us our pink slips.

To prevent this sort of thing from happening, the RFC specifies that we each independently [choose a UUID](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) to use as our `namespace`.  Namespaces will typically be fixed and associated with a specific system in which UUIDs are being generated, so we'll probably just hardcode this as a constant in some configuration file somewhere.  Thus, within my namespace (e.g. `87c9cdf7-101d-4c05-a89d-c7aaff3a3fcf`) I can trust that the UUID I generate for `John Smith` will always be the same.  But I can also count on it being different from any UUID you create since you'll be using a different namespace.  And so if/when our systems merge, there won't be any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.3) of the RFC, there is this step:

> Allocate a UUID to use as a "name space ID" for all UUIDs generated from names in that name space; see [Appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#appendix-C) for some pre-defined values.

As far as I understand this, the aim of this namespace is to ensure that using the same name with the same meaning will result in the same UUID, whereas using the same name with a different meaning will result in a different UUID. The namespace UUID is concatenated with the actual name, and both are hashed together.

The code snippet about the 6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 UUID comes from that section C. So when you use that as a namespace, you should use a URL as a name. For example, you'd call the function as

```
uuid_t result_uuid;
const char* url = "http://www.example.com/document.txt";
uuid_create_sha1_from_name(&result_uuid, NameSpace_URL, url, strlen(url));
```

In contrast to this, a UUID for the whole example.com domain would be created using

```
uuid_t result_uuid;
const char* domain = "example.com";
uuid_create_sha1_from_name(&result_uuid, NameSpace_DNS, domain, strlen(domain));
```